# Data extraction from website

Tags: javascript, json, curl, web-scraping

I want to get oil prices in each city via this website in a table format, I tried to copy each data by selecting the city and the station, but the amount of data is very huge
Is there any tool that can select each option and save the data it receives.
(The website receives responses in JSON)
The URL of the website is http://total.smarteez.eu/widget-prix/

Answer (score 0):

If you can get all oil prices by using REST API as a JSON try to use jQuery datatables. Following link to datatables

https://datatables.net/